# Pourquoi "comédiens" ?

Tags: théatre

Sait-on pourquoi le mot employé pour qualifier les acteurs de théâtre qui interprètent et les comédies et les tragédies, est "comédiens" (et non "tragédiens") ?

Answer (score 7):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* nous apprend qu'une *comédie* (mot apparu en 1370) est au départ une de pièce de théâtre sans considération de genre.

> Le sens plus précis de « pièce divertissante représentant des personnes de moyenne et basse condition  est apparu en 1552 » par opposition à tragédie, puis à drame.

Le dérivé **comédien, ienne** est attesté vers 1500 (*comediain*) et

> À la différence de **comédie**, il a conservé au sens propre,  dans un usage un peu snob ou professionnel, la valeur large d'« acteur » de théâtre ou de cinéma ».

À l'article **Tragédie** Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* dit que :

> **Tragédien, ienne** (1372 *tragedian*) d'abord appliqué à un acteur de théâtre tragique antique et étendu ensuite (1741) à un acteur moderne de tragédies, a eu du mal à s'implanter : il a été critiqué au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle et on lui a préféré *comédien*.

Je ne saurais pas dire, et je n'ai pas trouvé, pourquoi justement le terme de « comédien » a été préféré. Serait-ce le fait que « tragédien » a aussi à un moment désigné un auteur de tragédie ? (Voir [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/trag%C3%A9dien) : « Auteur de tragédies (sens peu usité) ».

Pour terminer cette citation de La Fontaine trouvée dans [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/trag%C3%A9dien) :

> "Aussi voyons-nous qu'on se sert indifféremment de ce mot de comédie, pour qualifier tous les divertissements du théâtre ; on n'a jamais dit : les tragédiens, ni allons à la tragédie", La Fontaine, Psyché, I, p. 92.

Answer (score 1):

Tragédien reste utilisé, cependant il ne s'applique qu'aux comédiens faisant exclusivement des tragédies.

> TRAGÉDIEN, -IENNE, subst. A.  Acteur, actrice qui interprète surtout
> des tragédies. Illustre, grand tragédien; art du tragédien; talent de
> tragédien.

[TLFi](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=2389782480;)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).